# Getting "unknown url" response from mongodb upon sending curl command

Tags: mongodb

Upon using below `curl...` in terminal to mongodb server in Cloud9 IDE, I'm getting an `unknown url` response back.

**Command**

```
curl http://localhost:28017/posts
```

**Response**

```
<html><body>unknown url</body></html>
```

Can anyone explain what this means?

Comment: It means `"unknown url"` of course, which means you got the url wrong. If you are trying to use the [HTTP Interface of MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#simple-rest-api) ( which I recommned you do not ). Then as the documentation states the format is: `http://127.0.0.1:28017/databaseName/collectionName/`. So you need "both" parts of `databaseName` and `collectionName`. You only have "one".

Comment: `If you are trying to use the HTTP Interface of MongoDB ( which I recommned you do not ).`... if you don't mind me asking, what do you recommend?

Comment: How about acutally reading the other infomation listed on that same manual page from the official website? But much like the content there, I don't do product endorsements. At least not without a substantial fee :)